# algorithm for testing mutliple substrings in multiple strings

Tags: python, algorithm, string, substring

I have several million strings, X, each with less than 20 or so words.  I also have a list of several thousand candidate substrings C.  for each x in X, I want to see if there are any strings in C that are contained in x.  Right now I am using a naive double for loop, but it's been a while and it hasn't finished yet...Any suggestions?  I'm using python if any one knows of a nice implementation, but links for any language or general algorithms would be nice too.

Comment: @ruslik: and how, exactly, would hashes help here?

Answer (score 4):

Encode one of your sets of strings as a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (I recommend the bigger set).  Lookup time should be faster than an imperfect hash and you will save some memory too.

Answer (score 1):

It's gonna be a *long* while.  You have to check every one of those several million strings against every one of those several thousand candidate substrings, meaning that you will be doing (several million * several thousand) string comparisons.  Yeah, that will take a while.

If this is something that you're only going to do once or infrequently, I would suggest using `fgrep`.  If this is something that you're going to do often, then you want to look into implementing something like the [Aho-Corasick string matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

If your x in X only contains words, and you only want to match words you could do the following:

Insert your keywords into a set, that makes the access log(n), and then check for every word in x if it is contained in that set.

like:

```
keywords = set(['bla', 'fubar'])
for w in [x.split(' ') for x in X]:
    if w in keywords:
        pass # do what you need to do
```

A good alternative would be to use googles re2 library, that uses super nice automata theory to produce efficient matchers. (http://code.google.com/p/re2/)

EDIT: Be sure you use proper buffering and something in a compiled language, that makes it a lot faster. If its less than a couple gigabytes, it should work with python too.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use regex

```
subs=re.compile('|'.join(C))  
for x in X:  
    if subs.search(x):  
        print 'found'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho-Corasick. You can build a pattern-matcher for a set of fixed strings in time linear in the total size of the strings, then search in text, or multiple sections of text, in time linear in the length of the text + the number of matches found.

Another fast exact pattern matcher is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin-Karp_string_search_algorithm